# Вычитать сообщения из потока байт

Tags: c++

Иметься поток байт, т.е. постоянно идут сообщения в байтах. Сообщения имеют разную длину. Все сообщения начинаются символом # (или в hex 0x23). Символ # может быть только в начале сообщения! Как вычитывать сообщения в массив char от символа # до след символа #, при разной длине сообщений при этом не терять сообщения? Поскольку они идут непрерывно с какой-то частотой.

К примеру поток байт:

**0x23**, 0х24, 0x50, 0x57, 0x52, 0x2C, 0x01, **0х23**, 0х34, 0x35, **0x23**, 0x25, 0x25, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x30, 0x31, 0x24, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, **0x23**, ...

В случае если одно сообщение байт:

```
uint8_t mess[] = {0х23, 0х34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x44};
char buffer[sizeof(mess) + 1];
memcpy(buffer, mess, sizeof(mess));
buffer[sizeof(mess)] = '\0';
if ((buffer[0] == '#' || buffer[0] == 0x23)
{
 // какие-то действия
}
```

Comment: Это невозможно, так как нет никакого способа отличить # в середине текущего сообщения от начала следующего.

Comment: А если сохранять посимвольно в вектор, до нахождения #?

Comment: Ну допустим насохраняли до нахождения #, как теперь определить, является ли это # частью сообщение или это начинается следующее?

Comment: Но мы значем, что все сообщения начинаются с #. т.е. начало потока идет с символа #

Comment: а в середине сообщения может быть символ # ?

Comment: Вот вам сообщение `#это#одно#сообщение` - как вы при нахождении # в середине определите, что оно еще не закончилось?

Comment: @user7860670, с чего вы вообще решили, что `#` может быть в середине сообщения?

Comment: сообщение может начинаться только с #. В середине сообщения не может быть #.

Comment: В вопросе этого не было указано

Comment: Добавил. Видимо меня не правильно поняли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class Reader
{
    std::string tail;
    public:
        void read(const std::string& s)
        {
            tail = tail+s;
            if (tail.empty()) return;
            assert(tail[0] == '#');
            while (true) {
                size_t f = tail.find('#',1);
                if (f == std::string::npos) return;
                std::string message = tail.substr(0, f);
                // отпроцессим сообщение - выведем в консоль
                std::cout << message << '\n';
                // можно было выше не копировать, а просто прислать кусок
                // удалим с хвоста
                tail.erase(0, f);
            }
        }
        std::string get_tail() const { return tail;}
};

int main(){
    Reader r;
    r.read("#123#11#");
    r.read("1111111");
    r.read("#9999#");
    r.read("###");

    std::cout << r.get_tail();
}
```

последнее сообщение всегда остается в буфере, так как мы не знаем, оно уже закончилось или нет. функция read получает данные произвольными кусками. В самом конце, когда соединение будет закрыто, можно взять последнее сообщение через get_tail. Остальные функции дописывайте по надобности.

Если у Вас в одном пакете приходят сразу много сообщений, то может есть смысл переделать  внутренности цикла, что бы не делать сколько копирований.

Comment: Спасибо. Почти разобрался в вашем коде. единственный вопрос остался, как полученные сообщения присвоить либо к string или в массив char? для того чтобы можно было работать с каждым проученным сообщением в отдельности.

Comment: есть разные способы. Можете складывать в массив, а потом доставать их. Или сделать функцию-колбек. тут все зависит от Вашей фантазии

Comment: так если сложить сообщения в массив, я получу первоначальную задачу, снова надо будет пробегать по массиву до совпадения с #. или я не прав?

Comment: не массив символов, а массив сообщений

Comment: я каждое `message` кладу в вектор прямо в функции `read`. Потом создаю функцию для печати вектора. Последнее сообщение теряеться. почему? и является ли этот способ нормальным, либо есть более локаничный способ?

Comment: я же написал о последнем сообщении. читайте внимательно-внимательно.

Comment: А чем вектор не массив сообщений? я не понимаю

Comment: вектор вполне нормальный массив. А последнее сообщение "теряется", потому что у Ваших сообщений нет символа конца, поэтому, для последнего куска мы не можем с уверенностью сказать, это уже полное сообщение или нет. Для этого и есть get_tail

Comment: т.е. получается, что я буду терять последнее сообщение. и чтобы его не терять мне надо в конце делать  `push_back(get_tail())` ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116721/discussion-between-andrei-and-kovadim).

Comment: к сожалению, Вы должны либо придумать как именно понять, что сообщение завершилось или добавлять последнее сообщение ручками. По другому похоже нельзя. А чаты... не знаю, зачем они.

Comment: я добавил в свою функцию печати добавление `tail` в конец вектора. Оно конечно работет. Но это выглядит как будто костыль какой-то.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что Вам приходят сообщения пачками и каждая новая пачка начинается с #. В таком случае код можно упросить

Comment: Как я понимаю. Мне по некому событию будет приходить массив байт, в котором будет содержаться n-ое количество сообщений, и все эти сообщения начинаются с `#`. Есть в таком случае смысл что-то упрощать?

Comment: если в сообщении содержится целое количество сообщений, то да

Comment: а не могли бы вы показать что можно упростить?

Comment: @Andrei, для упрощения достаточно перенести `#` из головы в хвост (а еще лучше заменить его на `'\n'`). Если это возможно. Мы же не видим весь протокол и не знаем, что у вас за задача.